# Class containing an array of unique pointer

Tags: c++

I have a class `A` that contains a vector of unique pointers to a class `V`. I would like to use a unique pointer of A. Unfortunately I am not able to do it as illustrated by the following code sample:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


struct V {
    V(int v) : value(v) {}
    int value;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<V> clone() const = 0;

    void write(std::ostream& os) const {
        os << value;
    }
};
struct W : public V {
    W(int v) : V(v) {}
    virtual std::unique_ptr<V> clone() const override {
        return std::make_unique<W>(*this);
    }
};

struct A {
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;
    A(A const& other) {
        vv_.reserve(other.vv_.size());
        for (const auto& v: other.vv_) {
            vv_.push_back(v->clone());
        }
    }
    A(A && other) = default;
    A& operator=(A const& other) {
        vv_.reserve(other.vv_.size());
        for (const auto& v: other.vv_) {
            vv_.push_back(v->clone());
        }
        return *this;
    }
    A& operator=(A && other) = default;

    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const = 0;

    void addV(std::unique_ptr<V> up_v) {
        vv_.push_back(std::move(up_v));
    }
    void write(std::ostream& os) const {
        for (const auto& up_v: vv_) {
            os << " ";
            up_v->write(os);
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<V>> vv_;
};

struct B : public A {
    B() = default;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<A> clone() const override {
        return std::make_unique<B>(*this);
    }
};


int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;                
    b->addV(std::make_unique<W>(1));     // This leads to program returned 139
    b->addV(std::make_unique<W>(2));
    b->write(std::cout);

    // B b;                              // This works as expected
    // b.addV(std::make_unique<W>(1));
    // b.addV(std::make_unique<W>(2));
    // b.write(std::cout);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I make this sample work ?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<B> b;` does not own any object and is empty; it is like a null pointer.

Comment: I am baffled. Thank you ... ;)

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<B> b = std::make_unique<B>();` would work.